# react-native: how to do search filter using autocomplete. Here is my sample

Tags: javascript, react-native

I select input then also it shows related text how to solve this. please help me

[this result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T3UI.png)

[I want this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhmCu.png)

Here is what I tried

```
 fetch('http://sample/?keyword='+searchText+'')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(async (json) => {
    const { contactList: data } = json;
    this.setState({ data });
 });
 const { data } = this.state;
 const regex = new RegExp(`${searchText.trim()}`, 'i');
 return data.filter(item => item.Name.search(regex) > -1);
```

Comment: `fetch('http://sample/?keyword='+searchText+'')` is **asynchronous** - so `const { data } = this.state;` won't be the result of that fetch

Comment: if I remove async then also it shows the same result.

Comment: Yes. Because fetch is asynchronous as I said